# ASSERTION ERROR: Issue in running SQL query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, debugging, assertion

**Question #1**

List all the directors who directed a 'Comedy' movie in a leap year. (You need to check that the genre is 'Comedy’ and year is a leap year) Your query should return director name, the movie name, and the year.

```
%%time
def grader_1(q1):
    q1_results  = pd.read_sql_query(q1,conn)
    print(q1_results.head(10))
    assert (q1_results.shape == (232,3))

    #m as movie , m_director as md,Genre as g,Person as p
    query1 ="""SELECT m.Title,p.Name,m.year
    FROM Movie m JOIN 
         M_director d
         ON m.MID = d.MID JOIN 
         Person p
         ON d.PID = p.PID JOIN
         M_Genre mg
         ON m.MID = mg.MID JOIN
         Genre g 
         ON g.GID = mg.GID
         WHERE g.Name LIKE '%Comedy%'
    AND ( m.year%4 = 0
    AND m.year % 100 <> 0
    OR  m.year % 400 = 0 ) LIMIT 2"""
    grader_1(query1)
```

ERROR:

```
                               title           Name  year
0                         Mastizaade   Milap Zaveri  2016
1  Harold & Kumar Go to White Castle   Danny Leiner  2004

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-17-a942fcc98f72> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('time', '', 'def grader_1(q1):\n    q1_results  = pd.read_sql_query(q1,conn)\n    print(q1_results.head(10))\n    assert (q1_results.shape == (232,3))\n\n#m as movie , m_director as md,Genre as g,Person as p\nquery1 ="""SELECT m.Title,p.Name,m.year\nFROM Movie m JOIN \n     M_director d\n     ON m.MID = d.MID JOIN \n     Person p\n     ON d.PID = p.PID JOIN\n     M_Genre mg\n     ON m.MID = mg.MID JOIN\n     Genre g \n     ON g.GID = mg.GID\n     WHERE g.Name LIKE \'%Comedy%\'\nAND ( m.year%4 = 0\nAND m.year % 100 <> 0\nOR  m.year % 400 = 0 ) LIMIT 2"""\ngrader_1(query1)')

2 frames

<decorator-gen-53> in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py in time(self, line, cell, local_ns)
   1191         else:
   1192             st = clock2()
-> 1193             exec(code, glob, local_ns)
   1194             end = clock2()
   1195             out = None

<timed exec> in <module>()

<timed exec> in grader_1(q1)

AssertionError:
```

I have run this SQL query on IMDB DATASET without grad_1 function, I am able to run this query. However when I try to run within grader_1 function. I am getting assertion error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your 'LIMIT 2' on the end of the query is preventing you getting more than 2 results. Removing it will allow you to get all the results (presumably 232 of them...)

Comment: Hi, I have removed it. But still getting an assertion error even though i am getting a result.

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL query directly on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a LIMIT clause, which prevents the SQL engine to fetch all data.
Just run it again without this clause.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even after removing LIMIT clause, I am still getting an error though i am getting the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
query1 = """ SELECT M.title,Pe.Name,M.year FROM Movie M JOIN M_Director MD              ON M.MID = MD.MID JOIN M_Genre MG ON M.MID = MG.MID JOIN Genre Ge ON MG.GID = Ge.GID JOIN Person Pe ON MD.PID = Pe.PID WHERE Ge.Name LIKE '%Comedy%' AND CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(M.year),-4) AS INTEGER) % 4 = 0 AND (CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(M.year),-4) AS INTEGER) % 100 <> 0 OR CAST(SUBSTR(TRIM(M.year),-4) AS INTEGER) % 400 = 0)                       """
```

Run this query all your problem resolves.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).